# Вызов потока по id

Tags: java, arraylist

Доброго времени суток. Java занимаюсь месяц.

Пишу клиент - серверное приложение. Похоже на обычный чат. Каждому новому соединению назначается `id`. Значение записывается в `ArrayList`. Каждый новый клиент открывается в отдельном потоке.

Никак не могу понять: как по `id`, отправить сообщение именно выбранному клиенту?

Каким образом вызвать метод `writeUTF`, связанный именно с этим `id`?

```
public class myLogic implements Runnable {
    Socket socket = null;
    public myLogic(Socket s){
        socket = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true){
            String line = br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(line);
            String line1 = dis.readUTF();
            dout.flush();
            dis.close();
        }
        }catch(Exception e){}

    }

}

public class SelectorTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        int port = 9007;
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true){
            int id = 0;
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            ArrayList AL = new ArrayList();
            AL.add(s);
            System.out.println(AL.toString());
            System.out.println(AL.containsAll(AL));
            AL.set(id, s);
            Runnable r = new myLogic(s);
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: покажите ваш код, можно будет ответить

Comment: Один момент. Сейчас добавлю.

Comment: где здесь массив `Socket`ов ?

Comment: ArrayList AL = new ArrayList(); AL.add(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

используйте `Map`

```
public class SelectorTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        int port = 9007;
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);

        Map<Integer, Socket> AL = new HashMap<>(); // тут будим хранит сокеты
        Integer id = 0;

        while(true){
            id++;
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            AL.put(id,s);
            ...
        }
    }
};
```

для получения

```
AL.get(id);
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное) Теперь мне все стало понятно) Еще раз большое спасибо)